# Standard object tabs in permission sets

Tags: standard-objects, permission-sets, tab

I am looking to use permission sets to manage access to standard Salesforce object tabs such as Accounts and Contacts.

The user in question has a profile with no permissions; All tabs are set to Tab Hidden. I am looking to apply a permission set to the user which would then grant access for that user to view the Account tab in the app.

I cannot find a way to grant Account tab visibility in my permission set.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Object Settings > Accounts.

[image: Account Settings]

If you don't see it as an option, it's because the License Type you selected does not support Accounts.

[image: Order Permission Set]

---

[image: Available Objects on this Permission Set]

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, this is what I thought as well. However, I am unable to see the Tab Settings section in the UI when selecting the Accounts object in custom objects. Could this be due to the particular edition I am on?

Comment: @markwilland Maybe? All I know is that you can't select Accounts as a type if the license doesn't support accounts. You may want to contact Support if you believe this is an error.

Comment: Ok, so would this not be possible on an unlicensed permission set? I just find it strange as that section is there for all custom objects but not for standard objects

Comment: @markwilland It depends on your org's available license types. In my dev org, for example, I'm allowed to select accounts on an unlicensed Permission Set, but depending on your features, you may not be able to do this. Try this with a Salesforce license, you should see Accounts as an option.